How do Einstein Summation and Voigt notation work together?
I've had some limited experience with linear algebra but I was recently introduced to the Einstein Summation convention and the Voigt Notation. However, I've been trying to understand how to apply these two together.
So, in the following matrix, how does on get to the first component $c_{11}l_{x}^{2}+c_{44}(1-l_{x}^{2})$?
\begin{equation}
    [\Gamma_{ij}] = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        c_{11}l_{x}^{2}+c_{44}(1-l_{x}^{2}) & (c_{12}+c_{44})l_{x}l_{y} & (c_{12}+c_{44})l_{x}l_{z}\\
        (c_{12}+c_{44})l_{y}l_{z} & c_{11}l_{x}^{2}+c_{44}(1-l_{y}^{2}) & (c_{12}+c_{44})l_{y}l_{z}\\
        (c_{12}+c_{44})l_{z}l_{x} & (c_{12}+c_{44})l_{z}l_{y} & c_{11}l_{z}^{2}+c_{44}(1-l_{z}^{2})\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The equation for $\Gamma_{ij}$ is:
\begin{equation}
    \Gamma_{ij} = l_{iK}c_{KL}l_{Lj}
\end{equation}
With the components $l_{iK}, c_{KL}$ and $l_{Lj}$:
\begin{equation}
    l_{iK} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & l_{z} & l_{y}\\
        0 & l_{y} & 0 & l_{z} & 0 & l_{x}\\
        0 & 0 & l_{z} & l_{y} & l_{x} & 0
    \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    l_{Lj} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_{x} & 0 & 0\\
        0 & l_{y} & 0\\
        0 & 0 & l_{z}\\
        0 & l_{z} & l_{y}\\
        l_{z} & 0 & l_{x}\\
        l_{y} & l_{x} & 0
    \end{bmatrix}, \quad
[c] =
    \begin{bmatrix}
        c_{11} & c_{12} & c_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        c_{12} & c_{11} & c_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        c_{12} & c_{12} & c_{11} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & c_{44} & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{44} & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{44}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Where $c_{12} = c_{11} - 2c_{44}$

I see no Voigt notation here.  Also, an angular momentum relation is used: $J_x^2 + J_y^2 = J^2 - J_z^2$ among the $l$s, where $|J| = 1$ seems to have been assumed.  For $\Gamma_{11}$, this assumption appears as $l_y^2 + l_z^2 = 1 - l_x^2$.

Then I mistinterpreted the capital letters L and K. But, how does the sum for the first index of $Gamma_{ij}$ come to be in that case? Which components are summed together, since I don't understand how to do that yet.

The "$K$" and "$L$" aren't really Einstein convention, they are matrix indices.  There is a quick translation to Einstein convention: $\Gamma_i{}^j = l_i{}^K c_K{}^L l_L{}^j$, but whether an index is lower or upper depends on whether it is covariant or contravariant (and I don't claim which is which here).
\begin{align*}
\Gamma_{11} &= l_{1K}c_{KL}l_{L1}  \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        l_{x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & l_{z} & l_{y}
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot c \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_{x} \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        l_{z} \\
        l_{y} 
    \end{bmatrix}  \\
    &= \begin{bmatrix}
        l_x c_{11} & l_x c_{12} & l_x c_{12} & 0 & l_z c_{44} & l_y c_{44}
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot
    \begin{bmatrix}
        l_{x} \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        l_{z} \\
        l_{y} 
    \end{bmatrix}  \\
    &= l_x^2 c_{11} + 0 + 0 + 0 + l_z^2 c_{44} + l_y^2 c_{44}  \\
    &= c_{11} l_x^2 + c_{44}( l_y^2 + l_z^2)  \\
    &= c_{11} l_x^2 + c_{44}(1 - l_x^2)  \text{,}
\end{align*}
where we have used the angular momentum relation from the comments to the Question.

Thank you very much for the clear answer! I was a bit confused in this case with the Voigt Notation, as that was also used in the rest of the theory with the capital letters K, L etc. However, since you mentioned the co- and contravariance: Are both the ways to write down the equation for $\Gamma_{ij}$ equivalent? When do I need to put an index up top or at the bottom?

@Benzv2001 : This, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Vector_representations , is probably clearer than I can be in a comment.

@Benzv2001 : The really overshort background for "why upper and/versus lower indices" is that one should not imagine taking the dot product of two vectors from the same space.  One should take a dot product of a vector and a linear function on that space.  For $\Bbb{R}^n$, the set of linear functions is isomorphic to the set of vectors, so it is easy to "fuzz" the difference between them.  In less flat spaces, the distinction really is a difference.
